# Why is my Array of pointers initialising as type Char?

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have attempted to declare an Array of pointers to an object I declared, as I want to be able to access the pointers of the stored objects.
Trouble is, the Array seems to somehow be of char pointers, as when I attempt to access elements via the pointers in the array, my function is incompatible since I'm attempting to access the pointer of the object type I declared.

```
DeclaredObject::DeclaredObject *pointerArray[X] //Where X is a previously defined positive integer

void SaveObject(DeclaredObject::DeclaredObject objectInstance, DeclaredObject::DeclaredObject* pointerToObject){
    pointerToObject->objectPropertyOne = objectInstance.getPropertyOne();
    pointerToObject->objectPropertyTwo = objectInstance.getPropertyTwo();
    .
    [Similar code omitted]    
}
```

My attempt to instantiate the SaveObject method:

```
DeclaredObject::DeclaredObject objectToSave = {Object Declaration}
DeclaredObject::DeclaredObject *locationToSave = &pointerArray[ElementToSaveAt];

SaveObject(objectToSave, locationToSave);
```

Comment: Create a [mcve]. You have several unresolved, irrelevant names in your code. Don't comment that something was defined, but instead define the variables and types that you use.

Comment: That `objectInstance` argument is by value, not a reference or pointer. So it would seem you're storing references into a local value. Perhaps, your code isn't very clear to me.

Comment: Do you get build errors? If so then please edit your question to include the full and unedited build output (as copy-pasted text). Do you get run-time errors or crashes? Then use a debugger to locate them in your program. Do you get unexpected results? Then please show the input to your program, plus the actual and expected output.

Comment: Use smart pointer instead of raw pointer and use containers instead of raw array

Comment: And unless polymorphism is needed then perhaps don't use pointers at all, but a container of *objects*? The more you can avoid pointers (and in modern C++ it's seldom any need to use outside of polymorphism) the better and easier your life will be.

Answer (score 0):

You have an array of `DeclaredObject::DeclaredObject *`.

`&pointerArray[ElementToSaveAt]` is a pointer to an element in the array - a `DeclaredObject::DeclaredObject **`.

You should use `pointerArray[ElementToSaveAt]`.